# How do I get the type of an object so that I can use it with instanceof?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm writing a program in Java and I have a method with a header such as `public void doSomething(Object o)` and I want to check if o is the appropriate type for a parameter of another method.  So what I have is:

```
public void doSomething(Object o)
{
    Method m = //get method of another method (using reflection)
    Class<?> cl = m.getParameterTypes()[0];  //Get the class of the 0th parameter
    if(o instanceof cl)         //compile error here
         //do something
}
```

However this doesn't work.  Can someone help please.  Thanks

Comment: what should be instance of what in order for the condition to be met?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake...This should be `o instanceof cl`

Comment: Would using `cl.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass)` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instanceof` takes a static type as a parameter, what you're looking for is a dynamic check  if `o` will work as a parameter to the method;

```
Object o = ...
Method m = ...
Class cl = m.getParameterTypes()[0];
if(cl.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass()))  // Is an 'o' assignable to a 'cl'?
{
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between a static type and what you have here?

Comment: @Nosrettap You're trying to see if `o` is an instance of a `cl`, however the compiler does not know the type of `cl` at compile time. If you know the type of `cl` at compile time, you can use the `instanceof` keyword.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
if(c1.isInstance(o))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
if (o.getClass().equals(cl))
```

instead.  I believe `instanceof` requires the actual type (like `String` and not `String.class`).

Comment: Is there no way to get the type if I have the class?

Comment: Or, there is a method called getGenericParameterTypes() that returns a `Type`, however again this doesn't work

Comment: That's not really what I mean by "type".  I believe the `instanceof` check happens at compile time and not at runtime.  So you can't programmatically perform this check.  But the solution I've posted above should do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: A couple of issues: 1. this will break if `o == null`, where `instanceof` wouldn't. 2. This requires that `o` is an instance of exactly `c1` - subclasses and interface implementations won't do.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis: actually the check most certainly happens at runtime - `instanceof` is translated to a `checkcast` operation in the bytecode. It's only the `instanceof` class argument that is determined at compile time...